# What is the 'life-cycle' of an issue or exception report

Tags: agile, product-management, reporting, prince2

What is the 'life-cycle' of an issue and exception report. I've seen the reports, and it looks like only one sheet that needs to filled out once. Of course, it may not be filled out completely at the same time, but I have no idea what 'life-cycle' means in this content.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when someone raises an issue or exception report?

Usually it is something like:

1. Preliminary evaluation of the problem- Is it reproducible? Is all the required information present, etc.
2. Pass to development for their evaluation of the impact and fix options
3. Review by a Change Board to accept or reject the change (or seek greater clarity), or perhaps add it to the list for a future release
4. Make the change (if approved)
5. System test the change
6. UAT the change
7. Close the issue or send back for more work

That is a lifecycle of an issue or exception, once raised, and the report or record of the issue or exception has to support that process in some way and information within it is usually changed to reflect status changes, new information and other relevant items, and that is its lifecycle; closely aligned to the lifecycle of the change itself.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate you help. I would mark your answer up, but I racked up enough points yet. :)